# Python 3 format csv with left aligned and re-write into a new csv

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have an unaligned CSV

```
symbol,latestPrice,changePercent,marketCap,peRatio,week52High,week52Low,ytdChange,companyName
SENS,2.91,0.41951,1245690090,,5.56,0.3497,2.7574315416379904,Senseonics Holdings Inc
RESN,4.07,0.25617,245922111,,8.33,2.09,0.7920190566037737,Resonant Inc
DOCU,233.24,0.19764,45378268496,-178.05,290.23,135.42,0.24685277552856497,DocuSign Inc
JOAN,16.92,0.18987,685586116,,17.01,9.75,0.5710944897959185,JOANN Inc
AMCX,66.8,0.17668,2052849170,12.53,83.63,20.16,1.0441667207156833,AMC Networks Inc - Class A
```

and try to reformat them and save it into a new csv

```
        with open(out_file, 'w') as csvfile:

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        for row in csv_f:
            print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<20} {:<25} '.format(*row))
            writer.writerows('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<20} {:<25} '.format(*row))
```

the print shows what I am trying to do

```
                       companyName  latestPrice  ...  week52Low  ytdChange
symbol                                           ...                      
SENS       Senseonics Holdings Inc         2.91  ...     0.3497   2.757432
RESN                  Resonant Inc         4.07  ...     2.0900   0.792019
DOCU                  DocuSign Inc       233.24  ...   135.4200   0.246853
JOAN                     JOANN Inc        16.92  ...     9.7500   0.571094
AMCX    AMC Networks Inc - Class A        66.80  ...    20.1600   1.044167
```

But the reformat CSV becomes like this. not readable at all

```
s
y
m
b
o
l
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
l
a
t
e
s
t
P
r
i
c
```

Could anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writer.writerows()` takes a collection of rows as the first parameter. Since you pass a string (a collection of characters), each character of the string is treated as a separate row. Use `writer.writerow()` instead.

`writer.writerow()`, on the other hand, takes a collection of columns. Be sure to pass to it a *list* of columns, not a single string, as in `writer.writerow([your_string])`.

Comment: Thank you. Used writer.writerow() here and the output csv looks better,but still look very weird. 
```s,y,m,b,o,l,``` instead of the expected format in print, which is ```symbol           ```. Could you enlighten?